# Object constrained along curve rotates unexpectedly when scrubbing timeline

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, normals, timeline

I want the ball's rotation to not be affected for testing purposes. I have animated the *Evaluation Time* of the curve. When I scrub the *Evaluation Time* part (the field I animated), it works as expected. But if I scrub the timeline, it tilts 30 degrees. I have

[image]

I tried straightening the handles which required me to change the tilt to 30 degrees since the curve turns 60 degrees, but not exactly sure. Why are scrubbing these 2 things yielding different results and how do I fix this? I don't want it to rotate. I just want it to follow the path because I will manually animate the rotation.

[image]

[image]*(Blender 3.5)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a rotation animation in the NLA, remove it:

[image]

Comment: ooooh! i totally forgot about it when i appended it from another file! thank you so much!